# Why is Mathematica converting Sin(x + pi/2) to Cos(x)?

Tags: plotting

My grandson and I are trying to plot `Sin[x]` and `Sin[x + pi/2]` on the same axis.

`Sin[x + pi/2]` should be similar in magnitude and frequency to the `Sin[x]` curve, but shifted pi/2 to the left. The problem is that Mathematica is converting `Sin[x + pi/2]` to `Cos[x]`. When we try to plot these together, we get the following:

[image]

As you can see, the `Sin[x + pi/2]` (now `Cos[x]`!) represented by the light-brown  curve is centered at the y-axis, instead of being shifted pi/2 to the left.  Also, the `Sin[x]` curve has been shifted to the right instead of being centered on the y-axis.

Why is this happening? Why is Mathematica converting `Sin[x + Pi/2]` to `Cos[x]`? Also, wouldn't you expect the `Sin[x]` curve (in blue) to also be centered on the y-axis?

Here's our code:

```
 y1[x_] := Sin[x];
 y2[x_] := Sin[x + Pi/2];
 a = -2 Pi; b = 2 Pi;
 Plot[{y1[x], y2[x]}, {x, a, b}]
```

Instead of `Pi` we have the symbol for pi in our actual code.

Comment: *"`Sin[x + Pi/2]` should be similar in magnitude and frequency to the `Sin[x]` curve but shifted Pi/2 to the left"*: ... and indeed it is! The yellow curve (`Sin[x + Pi/2]`) is the same as the blue curve, only shifted to the left by Pi/2. Coincidentally, `Sin[x + Pi/2]` is also equal to `Cos[x]`, but that is neither here nor there with respect to your issue; indeed, Sin and Cos differ in phase by exactly Pi/2. What am I missing here?

Comment: Secondarily, *wouldn't you expect the Sin[x] curve (in blue ) to also be centered on the y-axis?*: no, I wouldn't, since $\sin{0}=0$. Are you perhaps misunderstanding the colorings? Would adding `PlotLegends -> "Expressions"` help in clarifying here?

Comment: Everything seems to be correct. it coverts `Sin[x+Pi/2]` to `Cos[x]` because they are equivalent and `Cos[x]` is "simpler". Check the `TreeForm` of both expressions.

Comment: I have to say "Grandson and I are trying.." really got me. If you clarify your second question, I would be happy to give further details. My answer is really just the tip of the iceberg, but if you think I should explain any part in more detail, please feel free to comment.

Comment: So very sorry...Grandpa is a moron!  The curves are actually where they are supposed to be [Cos(0) = 1 & Sin(0) = 0].  The true question is: Why is MM converting the original expression to Cos[x]?  Which was answered by several of you!  Thanks!

Comment: @OilerMan No worries whatsoever. You and grandson are doing great :-)

Comment: This is why I love this place: It is rare in the internet, that such a question would be answered as polite as here :)

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Answer (score 27):

The reason why `Sin[x+Pi/2]` is converted to `Cos[x]` is, that it is the simplest form. This is the way Mathematica works. You input an expression and Mathematica tries to *normalize* it as much as possible by applying rules that are coded into the system. There are many many rules and more importantly, often you wouldn't recognize them as *transformations of expressions*. What about this

```
Plus[1, 1]
(* 2 *)
```

I hope you agree that you wouldn't complain about *this* transformation. In your case, it is exactly the same although it is not as obvious as `1+1`. `Cos[x]` is just the best form Mathematica could find after applying the rules of the system.

> Also, wouldn't you expect the Sin[x] curve (in blue ) to also be centered on the y-axis?

That is a question I don't understand, but `Sin[x]` just looks this way. Maybe you can clarify this a bit.

Answer (score 25):

`Sin[x + Pi/2]` can be written in an easier way due to mathematical formula:

> $\sin(a + b) = \sin(a)\cos(b) + \sin(b)\cos(a)$

Here, $a = x$ and $b = \pi/2$. You need to know that $\sin(\pi/2) = 1$ and $\cos(\pi/2) = 0$.

So you rewrite with the formula:

> $\sin(x + \pi/2) = \sin(x)\cos(\pi/2) + \sin(\pi/2)\cos(x)$
>
> $= \sin(x)\cdot 0 + 1\cdot \cos(x)$
>
> $= \cos(x)$

*Mathematica* just uses a simpler form but both expressions are **exactly the same**.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! Really nice that you started off by answering instead of asking a question. If you are unsure about the etiquette, feel free to take the introductory [Tour]. If you have any other question about the site and how everything works, feel free to visit the [chat] and say hello.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think the issue here is Mathematica at all; rather, I think you are confused about what the graph of $y=\sin x$ is supposed to look like.

The function $y=\sin x$ is not "centered on the $y$-axis"; rather, it has *odd* symmetry, i.e. $180^\circ$ rotational symmetry around the origin.  $y=\sin x$ is shown below:
[image]

The graph of $y=\sin (x + \pi/2)$ is the same as $y=\sin x$ but shifted $\pi/2$ units (i.e. one-quarter period) to the left, which has the effect of moving the maximum to the $y$-axis:
[image]

This function, unlike the "unshifted" version, *is* symmetric across the $y$-axis.  And it also happens to be completely identical with the function $y=\cos x$, which has even symmetry.

So now go back to the original graph you included in your post.  The blue curve, $y=\sin x$, has **not** "been shifted to the right instead of being centered on the y-axis".  It's right where it's supposed to be, and should not be centered on the $y$-axis.  When you *do* shift it to the left, *then* it ends up centered on the $y$-axis, and exactly equal to the cosine function.

Comment: I guess you did not see my comment above.  You are absolutely correct!